# CSS - Make content line up

Tags: html, css

I have 3 td tags which contain some text and a button after the text. I want the buttons to line up even if the td contains different amounts of text.

I don't want to set a fixed height on the paragraph section because that will limit the amount of text that can be typed in. Is there a way to do this?

Here's a screen shot of what it looks like:

http://s23.postimage.org/cnp1f70vv/Untitled_1.jpg

Here's the HTML code (Apologies):

```
<td width="300" valign="top" height="114">
    <div class="imageTextOverlay_1">BOOK A VISIT</div>
    <a href="/visit-us.aspx">
    <img width="300" height="136" alt="Visit Beaufort Court" src="/media/1281571/visit_us.jpg">
    </a>
<h3>Visit Beaufort Court</h3>
<p>If you would like to find out more about wind energy, solar power, borehole cooling or biomass then come and visit us at Beaufort Court. We welcome schools, colleges, universities, professional bodies and community groups.</p>
<a class="imageButtonOverlay" href="/visit-us.aspx">Book Now >></a>
</td>
```

Here is the CSS for the buttons:

```
.imageButtonOverlay {
    background-color: #78A22F;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px 0 20px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, added it in now.

Comment: I can't believe such a simple fix never crossed my mind! Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Madness: no problem. Please mark the most appropriate answer as accepted if and when you get the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're already using a table, you could simply separate your buttons onto a new row:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><!-- First paragraph --></td>
            <td><!-- Second paragraph --></td>
            <td><!-- Third paragraph --></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><!-- First button --></td>
            <td><!-- Second button --></td>
            <td><!-- Third button --></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QLePR/1).

Comment: How can it be ugly?  Tables are cool again for layout in HTML5, especially when qualified with border="0".

Answer (score 0):

You could set the position of the button by a CSS `position:absolute`, like following :

```
td {
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}
td .imageButtonOverlay {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to `td` and `position:absolute` to `a class`

```
td{
    background:yellow;
    position:relative
}
.imageButtonOverlay{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xc3RK/2/)**

Comment: Similar answer as mine... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Paragraph 1</td>
      <td>Paragraph 2</td>
      <td>Paragraph 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:right"><input type="button" value="Button 1" /></td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><input type="button" value="Button 2" /></td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><input type="button" value="Button 3" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```